# How to set up proxy behind redash server

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, redash

My redash server is running on ubuntu by using aws AMI instance

**Now I want to set up a proxy server for my redash server??**

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the nginx configuration if you place a `nginx.conf` file under `/opt/redash/nginx`
You can set up your configuration there. After that, you would need to run `docker-compose restart nginx` to restart nginx with the new configuration